# How start a Php application in a specific time

Tags: php, jquery

i have to do an application in php but i don't known how make one things.
I want that (for example) every day at the 10 o clock my app begin to work.
At the moment it isn't important the content of the application but how i can start it at these time.

Comment: You should research [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) or similar software

Comment: And/Or Task Scheduler if you are on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use cron job if you use linux